# Simplify jQuery code - slide and slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide, slidetoggle

How can I simplify current JavaScript code? It looks too complicated.

```
// Data from AJAX response
var errorsJSON = {
    "name-pl": ["The name-pl field is required."],
    "name-en": ["The name-en field is required."]
}

var errorString = $(this).data('validate-multiple');
var errorNamesArray = errorString.split(", ");
var ul = $('<ul class="list-unstyled">');

$.each(errorNamesArray, function(key, value) {
    if (errorsJSON.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        ul.append(`<li><span class="help-block">${errorsJSON[value]}</span></li>`);
    }
});

if (! $(this).is(':visible') && ul.children('li').length > 0) {
    $(this).find('div.controls').empty().append(ul);
    $(this).slideDown(500);
} else if ($(this).is(':visible') && ul.children('li').length === 0) {
    $(this).slideUp(500);
} else if ($(this).is(':visible') && ul.children('li').length > 0) {
    $(this).slideUp(500, function() {
        $(this).find('div.controls').empty().append(ul);
        $(this).slideDown(500);
    });
}
```

Here I pasted both html and js code http://jsfiddle.net/ecLjnnhm/
I would like to point out that `errorsJSON` can change and depends what user put in the input fields.

Comment: A better idea: Instead of just pasting your code and saying "make it better", why not just tell us what your end goal is? It's hard to make your code better without any idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: My goal is to simplify toggling logic. It is very nested. I tried to use `slideUp()` on the start and then `slideDown()` on the end, but these functions have been animated div without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Readability**: Use variables to store the conditions of your `if` statements instead of lengthy declarations each time.

**Efficiency**: Cache `$(this)` as a variable so jQuery only has to do the work once.

**Personal preference**: I'd suggest prefacing any jQuery object variables (like `ul` in your case) with a `$` to indicate that they're a jQuery object.

```
// Data from AJAX response
var errorsJSON = {
    "name-pl": ["The name-pl field is required."],
    "name-en": ["The name-en field is required."]
}

var errorString = $(this).data('validate-multiple');
var errorNamesArray = errorString.split(", ");
var $ul = $('<ul class="list-unstyled">');
var $t = $(this);
var isVisible = $t.is(':visible');
var hasErrors = false;

$.each(errorNamesArray, function(key, value) {
    if (errorsJSON.hasOwnProperty(value)) {
        $ul.append(`<li><span class="help-block">${errorsJSON[value]}</span></li>`);
        hasErrors = true;
    }
});

if (!isVisible && hasErrors) {
    $t.find('div.controls').empty().append(ul);
    $t.slideDown(500);
} else if (isVisible && !hasErrors) {
    $t.slideUp(500);
} else if (isVisible && hasErrors) {
    $t.slideUp(500, function() {
        $t.find('div.controls').empty().append(ul);
        $t.slideDown(500);
    });
}
```